# Using javascript to show html on every page except one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i use a tracking software which allows me to dynamically load an html and css file but the html is embedded inside a JS currently i use this (1) js to load the html on the selected pages but how can tell the js to load n all pages EXCEPT 2 pages..

(1)

js:

```
if (window.location.href == 'http://support.example.com/support/default.asp' ||
    window.location.href == 'http://support.example.com/support/default.asp?pg=pgOldMainMenu' ||
    window.location.href == 'http://support.example.com/support/default.asp#') 
    {$('#mainArea').before(''}
```

Comment: Your missing a closing parentheses for .before

Comment: i just copied it wrong in my code i have it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just reverse the `==` conditionals to `!=` for the pages you don't want to load the content into.

Honestly a regular expression would look a hell of a lot cleaner... and the best bet would be to not load this JavaScript (or at least don't execute it) on the pages you don't want.

Comment: Try replacing the `||` with `&&` too. That way it reads "if the URL does not equal this AND the URL does not equal this"